# Jooq: Insert multiple records as batch

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, jooq

So I only use Jooq to build queries, but not to execute queries, like following:

```
AsyncTransactionalConnection conn = getAsyncTransactionalConnection();
InsertResultStep<PersonRecord> insert = /* create insert statement ... */;
conn.asyncExecute(insert);
```

The `conn` object can execute a query `conn.asyncExecute(org.jooq.Query query)`.
So my question is, how can I create a batch insert query of type `org.jooq.Query`?
Specifically, given a list `List<InsertResultStep<PersonRecord>>`, how can I create an instance of `org.jooq.Query` for that entire list?

Note that I am aware of other questions asking about how to do batch insert with Jooq, but they used Jooq to execute queries just like the answer from Jose Martinez below, while here I only use Jooq to build queries and use other mechanism to execute queries. Not my choice, but the system has been like that.

Answer (score 0):

From the DSLContext you can create a batch and execute it at the same time.

```
dslContext.batch(
    create.insertInto(AUTHOR, ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME).values(1, "Erich"  , "Gamma"    ),
    create.insertInto(AUTHOR, ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME).values(2, "Richard", "Helm"     ),
    create.insertInto(AUTHOR, ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME).values(3, "Ralph"  , "Johnson"  ),
    create.insertInto(AUTHOR, ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME).values(4, "John"   , "Vlissides"))
.execute();
```

The `batch(...)` functions in DSLContext do not return a Query object, but instead a Batch object (that is not a subtype of Query).  See the [API docs](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.11.x/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#batch-org.jooq.Query...-) for more info.

Comment: this is one query insert or multiquery?

Comment: its multiple inserts executed at the same time.  this is called batching.  it reduces network traffic and processing on the server.